# HOW is the Request.UserLanguages array sorted - by priority or alphabetically?

Tags: asp.net, localization, internationalization, http-headers, httprequest

I know from the [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that the `Request.UserLanguages` array is "sorted".  What they don't say is whether the array is sorted by *priority* or *alphabetically*.

For example, if my Accept-Languages header reads like this:

```
Accept-Language: gr, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7
```

The *priority* sorting would be "gr", with a value of 1, followed by "en-gb" with a 0.8 value and then "en" with 0.7.

The *alphabetical* sorting would be "en", "en-gb", "gr".

I can't figure out how to test this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order the items appear (comma-separated) in the *Accept-Language* header is the order they'll appear in the *UserLanguages* property.  The ";q=xx" portion isn't treated specially.  You can test this by using a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to submit arbitrary Accept-Language headers to the server and seeing the result of the UserLanguages property.

If you want to see the particular implementation of HttpRequest.UserLanguages, you can look at the [related .NET Framework source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=UserLanguages).

Comment: The documentation clearly specifies that the array is sorted - but the source code (thanks for the tip) just as clearly doesn't sort jack.  What a rip off!  ;-)